# Configure Qt 5.1 (mingw 4.8) and openCV 2.4.6

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, mingw

Can anyone show me a guide how to configure Qt 5.1 to work with openCV?

A configured and built openCV with WITH_QT flag on. The make, make install step was successful. I have now an install folder with header, and a bin (*.dll) and a lib (*.dll.a) folder.

I'm mainly interested in the

```
LIBS += ???
```

part. I have seen a wide variety of *.pro files, not a working one. My solution (bin folder added to path):

```
INCLUDEPATH += D:/Development/OpenCV/opencv-mingw-qt5/install/include

LIBS += D:/Development/OpenCV/opencv-mingw-qt5/install/lib/libopencv_calib3d246.dll.a
LIBS += D:/Development/OpenCV/opencv-mingw-qt5/install/lib/libopencv_contrib246.dll.a
LIBS += D:/Development/OpenCV/opencv-mingw-qt5/install/lib/libopencv_core246.dll.a
LIBS += D:/Development/OpenCV/opencv-mingw-qt5/install/lib/libopencv_features2d246.dll.a
LIBS += D:/Development/OpenCV/opencv-mingw-qt5/install/lib/libopencv_flann246.dll.a
LIBS += D:/Development/OpenCV/opencv-mingw-qt5/install/lib/libopencv_gpu246.dll.a
LIBS += D:/Development/OpenCV/opencv-mingw-qt5/install/lib/libopencv_imgproc246.dll.a
LIBS += D:/Development/OpenCV/opencv-mingw-qt5/install/lib/libopencv_highgui246.dll.a
LIBS += D:/Development/OpenCV/opencv-mingw-qt5/install/lib/libopencv_legacy246.dll.a
LIBS += D:/Development/OpenCV/opencv-mingw-qt5/install/lib/libopencv_ml246.dll.a
LIBS += D:/Development/OpenCV/opencv-mingw-qt5/install/lib/libopencv_nonfree246.dll.a
LIBS += D:/Development/OpenCV/opencv-mingw-qt5/install/lib/libopencv_objdetect246.dll.a
LIBS += D:/Development/OpenCV/opencv-mingw-qt5/install/lib/libopencv_photo246.dll.a
LIBS += D:/Development/OpenCV/opencv-mingw-qt5/install/lib/libopencv_stitching246.dll.a
LIBS += D:/Development/OpenCV/opencv-mingw-qt5/install/lib/libopencv_superres246.dll.a
LIBS += D:/Development/OpenCV/opencv-mingw-qt5/install/lib/libopencv_ts246.a 
LIBS += D:/Development/OpenCV/opencv-mingw-qt5/install/lib/libopencv_video246.dll.a
LIBS += D:/Development/OpenCV/opencv-mingw-qt5/install/lib/libopencv_videostab246.dll.a
```

When is start debug/release:

```
Starting D:\Qt\Projects\mVsion\build-mVsion-Default-Debug\debug\mVsion.exe...
The program has unexpectedly finished.
D:\Qt\Projects\mVsion\build-mVsion-Default-Debug\debug\mVsion.exe exited with code -1073741515

Starting D:\Qt\Projects\mVsion\build-mVsion-Default-Release\release\mVsion.exe...
SHIMVIEW: ShimInfo(Complete)
The program has unexpectedly finished.
D:\Qt\Projects\mVsion\build-mVsion-Default-Release\release\mVsion.exe exited with code -1073741515
```

Any idea?